# Running a flask app with nginx and gunicorn

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm new at this and have only been using nginx to serve static files. I have now installed flask and gunicorn. If I run `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.2:8000 hello:app` and then wget it from the server it works well. If I try to access it from a browser, however, it returns a 404 error (I am running this on a server that hosts a wordpress site which is locatet at root).

The flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello world!"

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And the relevant part of my nginx configuration:

```
location /flask {
                 proxy_set_header       Host            $http_host;
                 proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_\
for;
                 proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.2:8000;
                 proxy_redirect         off;
    }
```

I hope this is all the relevant info. If not, do tell. Thanks!

Comment: Should be `from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is how I serve my flask apps in Nginx:

Run gunicorn daemonized using a socket:

```
  sudo gunicorn app:app --bind unix:/tmp/gunicorn_flask.sock -w 4 -D
```

Related nginx config:

```
    upstream flask_server {
        # swap the commented lines below to switch between socket and port
        server unix:/tmp/gunicorn_flask.sock fail_timeout=0;
        #server 127.0.0.1:5000 fail_timeout=0;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        server_name example.com;

        keepalive_timeout 5;

        # path for static files
        location  /static {
            alias /path/to/static;
            autoindex on;
            expires max;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                proxy_pass http://flask_server;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Switched the configuration and it still returns a 404 Not Found error :/

Comment: I figured out what it was - I had my location in nginx config at /flask2 and then in my flask app @app.route('/') when it should have also been /flask2

Comment: Also, I never needed to do app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app). What is the purpose of doing that?

Comment: you don't need to do it, but it sets the host from X-Forwarded-Host and the remote address from X-Forwarded-For from your nginx config (proxt_set_header X-Forwarded-For)

Comment: Where is nginx config located?