# Nginx reverse proxy for flask

Tags: python, nginx, proxy, flask, gunicorn

I'm using Flask + Gunicorn + Nginx

I have a domain `example.digital` and a sub domain `api.example.digital`

In flask I have 3 blueprints.
Blueprint for `api` is registered using `subdomain='api'` and I have set `SERVER_NAME` config to `example.digital`

Everything seems to be working fine on my system (Windows no gunicorn and nginx). But on my server there is a problem. I have setup 2 virtual hosts with reverse proxy. My config is as follows

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.digital;

    location / {

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /static {
            alias  /home/ubuntu/backend/codes/static;
    }
}
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.digital;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

`api.example.digital` is working fine but there is a problem with main domain `example.digital`. Nothing except main page is loading. if I access `example.digital` main page loads but `exapmle.digital/login` shows 404.

Comment: What happens if you remove `$request_uri` from the `proxy_pass` directives?

Comment: Now its working. Same config. I think there was some problem with some .pyc files being included in the repository.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660118/running-a-flask-app-with-nginx-and-gunicorn?rq=1