# flask can't load static files when using nginx

Tags: nginx, flask

I'm using flask + gunicorn for my website. and I'm using nginx for reverse proxy only. and set up as nginx config [flask proxy setups](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups). I haven't added location /static info in nginx.conf file. so all static files are supposed to be handled by flask itself. but when visiting from public network, it can't load css files. I tried to run flask + gunicorn alone without nginx, it worked well. so why can't flask serve static files by itself behind nginx?

Then I added location /statis info into nginx config file so that nginx may serve static file instead. Still can't load static files. when i looked into error log. it shows

> "/var/www/my_project_folder/static/css/style.css" failed (2: No such
>   file or directory), client: 61.152.126.178, server: _, request: "GET
>   /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1", host: "47.97.209.250", referrer:
>   "http://47.97.209.250"

the path in the error message actually is correct. the last method I tried is to run all script and service under root and chmod my_project to 666. still no success.

I searched on stackoverflow, but no one mentioned the issue that flask itselft can't serve static files behind nginx.

So i hope anyone have any idea or clue about this. and nginx serving issue

Thank

Comment: config your static path for flask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a flask app with nginx and gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660118/running-a-flask-app-with-nginx-and-gunicorn)

Comment: @FrankAK, you mean the static path in nginx conf or in flask template? In template i use url_for('static', filename='css/style.css'), which I don't think i need to modify, since i move the whole project to var/www/my_project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:
https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/avkjh0/ask_flask_serve_static_files_from_flask_app_via/

nginx.sh:

```
USE_STATIC_PATH=${STATIC_PATH:-'/app/static'}
```

```
location /webappB/static {
  #alias /path/to/webappB/static;
  alias $USE_STATIC_PATH;
}
```

main.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/webappA")
```